# Azure logic app http post multipart/form-data file upload

Tags: java, azure, http, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to get call an api with the HTTP logic app within Azure

I am able to make the call successful through post man. see my post man configuration

[image: Post Man Configuration]

I can see the http code from postman as this, I am using this to make the logic app to be formatted similar to what post man has.

```
POST /dcma/rest/initiateOcrClassifyExtract HTTP/1.1

Host: godemo.ephesoft.com

Authorization: Basic NDU=??????

Cache-Control: no-cache

Postman-Token: 3baf23e7-6b46-a5f4-094b-3df1879bbe21

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="000001.pdf"; filename="000001.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf


------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="batchClassIdentifier"

BC590

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

below is the actual logic app http configuration.

[image: Logic App config]

the logs on the server show the below error

```
    2017-09-07 20:12:51,784 [ajp-apr-8009-exec-3] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/dcma].[DispatcherServlet]- Servlet.service() for servlet [DispatcherServlet] in context with path [/dcma] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Header section has more than 10240 bytes (maybe it is not properly terminated)] with root cause
org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException: Header section has more than 10240 bytes (maybe it is not properly terminated)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.readHeaders(MultipartStream.java:541)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:999)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:965)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:331)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:351)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1070)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:912)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.ephesoft.dcma.webapp.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.ephesoft.dcma.webapp.SessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:230)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.ephesoft.dcma.webapp.HTTPHeaderFilter.doFilter(HTTPHeaderFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
```

Comment: Does my answer helps you? Any Progress?

Answer (score 3):

For multipart/form-data there is now an example in the official documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#content-with-multipartform-data-type

```
"body": {
   "$content-type": "multipart/form-data",
   "$multipart": [
      {
         "body": "<output-from-trigger-or-previous-action>",
         "headers": {
            "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=file; filename=<file-name>"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

And if there are other form fields to send, just add similar objects with correct form field names.

The Content-Disposition header will need escaped quotes for the *name* and *filename* field if you are not using the TriggerBody from a previous step.

```
"Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"<file-name>\""
```

Answer (score 1):

From the log message you offered, I found that you used the `apache.commons.fileupload` library in the backend.
So,I created a simple servlet web project which contains the core code as below with the `apache.commons.fileupload` library to process uploaded files.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

@WebServlet("/HelloWorldByPostman")
public class HelloWorldByPostman extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public HelloWorldByPostman() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

//      String savePath = this.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/upload");

        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request); 
        System.out.println(isMultipart);

        if(isMultipart){  
            FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();  
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);  
            List<FileItem> items = null;  
            try {
                items=upload.parseRequest(request);
                System.out.println(items.toString());  
            } catch (FileUploadException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }  
            Iterator<FileItem> iterator = items.iterator();  
            while(iterator.hasNext()){  
                FileItem item = iterator.next();  
                if(item.isFormField()){  
                    System.out.println("is txt........"+item.getFieldName());  
                }else{  
                    System.out.println("is file..........."+item.getFieldName());  
                }  
            }  
        }  

        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append("jaygong");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Then,I deployed the project to `Azure Web App` so that I can upload files via http request.

***Postman:***

[image]

[image]

***Result:***
[image]

***Logic App:***

[image]

***Result:***

[image]

When the action is `post` and Content-Type type is `multipart/form-data`, the browser will take the form to control unit segmentation, and for each part plus Content-Disposition (form-data or file), Content-Type (default is text/plain), name (name control) and other information, and add a boundary.

The `Content-Type` attribute is already included in `Body` part so you could remove the `Content-Type` setting in `Header` part and retry your post request.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Could you share the `function.json` of `HelloWorldByPostman` please?

Answer (score -1):

you need to pass the data like
In body

```
{
  "$Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "$formdata": [
    {
      "key": "grant_type",
      "value": "client_credentials"
    },
    {
      "key": "client_id",
      "value": "your clientid"
    },
    {
      "key": "client_secret",
      "value": "your client secret"
    }
  ]
}
```